# Reflection to execute code in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly returns null

Tags: c#, system.reflection

According to [.Net Framework Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,bd671af9926207e9), GetExecutingAssembly use following code to get assembly.

```
public static Assembly GetExecutingAssembly()
{
    StackCrawlMark stackMark = StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller;
    return RuntimeAssembly.GetExecutingAssembly(ref stackMark);
}
```

Use System.Reflection to call this method works.

```
Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Assembly")
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("GetCallingAssembly"))
    .First().Invoke(null, null)
```

However, if I use reflection to call the code inside `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`, it always returns null.

```
Type.GetType("System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly")
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("GetExecutingAssembly")).Skip(1)
    // the second overload takes one argument
    .First().Invoke(null, new object[]  {
        Type.GetType("System.Threading.StackCrawlMark")
        .GetEnumValues().GetValue(1) // System.Threading.StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller
    })
```

Is there any explanation why it returns null?

Comment: In original source code `stackMark` is local variable (so it located on stack) and it passed by reference, thus `RuntimeAssembly.GetExecutingAssembly` get reference inside stack frame where that local variable resides, so it can locate that stack frame and can compute `StackCrawlMark.LookForMyCaller` relative to that stack frame. While you are passing reference to array element, but not reference to local variable on stack.

Comment: It gives me parameter Mismatch exception, when invoking the returned method, actually "the second overload"  which is a pInvoke takes two arguments, and returns void

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I guess it depends on CLR version. In my enviroment, the first is the pinvoke one.

Comment: That can't be, if the first one is the pinvoke for you then the second sample code you provided won't work.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa There is only one GetCallingAssembly(public, in second snippet) but two GetExecutingAssembly(internal, in third snippet).